# Move UniVerse data into SQL Server 2014 using u2 Toolkit

Tags: ssis, bids, universe, u2netdk

I am attempting to migrate a UniVerse database into SQL Server 2014. I have downloaded and installed the U2 toolkit for .net from Rocket software. The U2 provider is displayed in the dropdown list and I have entered all the required info in the Connection Manager window. Once I have entered the info, I test the connection and it connects successfully. But when I try to access the dropdown to view the available tables within the UniVerse database, the tables fail to load. Also when I try to use an SQL command instead, I receive and error that states that the table I selected in my query does not exist. In addition to those errors, I have applied the same configuration to an alternate development server and I receive an IBM Informix error. I have provided screenshots and OS information below.

I logged to HS.ADMIN on my UniVerse database to configure for odbc access, but I still have not had any success. I am new to UniVerse/UniData databases so it could be that I am just doing something flat out wrong. Any guidance/resources would be greatly appreciated.

Has anyone out there been able to connect to a U2 provider source with SSIS?

**Windows OS**
Microsoft SQL Server 2014
Visual Studios 2013 Ultimate (BIDS)
Windows Server 2012 R2

**Rocket u2**
UniVerse DBMS ver 11.2.4.0
u2 ToolKit for .NET ver 2.2

[Table does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6Jdq.jpg)

[IBM Informix error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC37t.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used SSIS directly with U2 provider source. However, I have used a U2.NET toolkit provider source with C#.

In my experience, the core query mechanism for the U2 .NET toolkit is shared with the ODBC provider. Therefore, I recommend focusing on getting ODBC running first. Although it sounds like you've already seen it, make sure you check out how to configure your UniVerse account for ODBC per [Rocket's ODBC documentation](http://static.miklos.ca/docs/UniVerse/Uvodbc.pdf) (specifically pages 2-4 and 2-5). I have often verified my ODBC setup using [Excel's external data access tools](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Using_the_ODBC_Driver_in_Excel_2010). Try starting small, allowing a couple files/table and then checking if you can query them in ODBC.